# not receiving any values from php server

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to retrieve all names from my database and send it to all the registered phones by gcm.

I get an error at my android side

Error

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at reminder.com.org.remind.GCMPushReceiverService.onMessageReceived(GCMPushReceiverService.java:27)
```

this is the result of var_dump($message)

```
array(1) { ["message"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "name1" [1]=> string(5) "name2" [2]=> string(5) "name3" } }
```

Please help. Thanks.

PHP Server Code

```
<?php

    include('db_connect.php');
    DEFINE('GOOGLE_API_KEY','my_google_api_key');

        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        $conn = $db->connect();

    $gcmRegids = array();
    $names = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Test";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($gcmRegids, $row['reg_id']);
        array_push($names, $row['name']);          
    }

    if(isset($gcmRegids)) { 
                $e = "ads";
        $message = array('message' => $names);
                var_dump($message);
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotification($gcmRegids,$message);
    }


    function sendPushNotification($reg_ids, $message) {
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $reg_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key='. GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if($result === false) {
            die('Curl failed:'. curl_error($ch));
        }

        curl_close($ch);
        //echo $result;
        return $result;
    }
?>

array(1) { ["message"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "name1" [1]=> string(5) "name2" [2]=> string(5) "name3" } }
```

Android code

```
public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {
    public final static String s = "msg";
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
            if(data != null) {
                arr = data.getStringArrayList("message");
                Log.d("Names:",arr.get(0));
            }
    }

    .....
 }
```

Comment: `Log.d("Names:",arr.get(0));` gives NullPointerException because `arr` is null. Do not blindly log. Check arr for null before use.

Comment: @greenappsI know. but why?

Comment: i think the arraylist is already initialize...so how null?

Comment: `data.getStringArrayList("message");` delivers null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get simply an Php Array into Android/java array .. you have to convert it.. try to change your php script as..

```
$message = array('message' => json_encode($names));
```

it will convert your php array($names) into json.
than get the JSON in android as..

```
        String message = data.getString("message");

        Log.e(TAG, "Message: " + message);

       now convert it into JsonArray as..

       JsonArray array = new JsonArray(message);
```

now loop on it and get the content of Php array names.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you are doing wrong.

change your code as below and try again

```
if (isset($gcmRegids) && count($gcmRegids) > 0) {
    $e = "ads";
    $message = array('message' => $names);
    var_dump($message);
    foreach ($gcmRegids as $gcmid) {
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotification($gcmid, $message);
    }
}
```